# Problem with SN7407 output

Tags: integrated-circuit, buffer, pullup, dsp, open-collector

I'm carrying out an experiment using an [SN7407](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn7407), which is an open-collector output buffer.

The use of this IC is to make the pulses (PWM) coming from a DSP (~3.3 V) be sent to a gate-driver circuit (~15 V). For this, I built the following circuit:

[image: Implemented circuit]

Two sources were used for the assembly, where the first one feeds the IC with +5 V and the second one is located in the 1Y output of the IC.

The pull-up resistor at the output has a value of 1 kΩ, while the "load" is represented by a 10 kΩ resistor.

When reading the signal on the load on the oscilloscope, I verified that this signal has a smaller amplitude than the desired one (approximately 13 V), around 6 V only.

[image: Signals read from the oscilloscope]

The yellow signal is the voltage across the resistor that represents the load, while the blue signal is the signal coming from the DSP (PWM1A).

The resistor should be larger than 375 Ω, ensuring that the current stays below 40 mA (IC limit). The voltage present at the load must be greater than 13 V when there is a high signal at the IC input. So the 1 kΩ resistor satisfies both requirements. Additionally, there is a 100 Ω resistor at the IC output, in series with the 10 kΩ load.

Are there any incorrect considerations in the pull-up resistor definition?

Circuit schematic:

[image: Circuit schematic]

Note: The issue was resolved by purchasing the IC from a different vendor. Apparently, the first IC used was not exactly the SN7407, but the 74LV07, which clamps the voltage at approximately 6V.

Comment: do you see the break in the red snd blue lines to the left of the `1K`? ... that break is also electrical

Comment: @jsotola Looks like there's a jumper across it.

Comment: There is the 74LV07 version of this chip, it will clamp the output voltage around 6 V as you describe. Do you use this one accidentally?

Comment: @Jens In CI the recorded nomenclature is just SN7407, so this is a real possibility. I will look for this same IC in another seller and return with the feedback.

Comment: That's a pretty odd way to use an open collector output.  Typically, you would just have the load tied high and going to the collector

Comment: Where did you get the SN7407 from?

Comment: Are all your scope inputs set to high impedance?

Comment: I made the purchase of the same IC from a different supplier and the output worked correctly. So the problem was located in the CI as quoted by @Jens. Thank you all.

Comment: That's still a weird way to use an open collector output.

Answer (score 1):

At the output you have a pull-up and a pull-down:
[image: partial schematic].

When the buffer is on (low), you will see ~ 0 V. When high (off), you will see \$15\,\textrm{V} \times \frac{R_3+R_L}{R_L+R_3+R_4}\$. This should be about 14 V. Are you sure you don't have 1k for RL ?

Comment: The RL resistor has a value of 10k (measured).

Comment: remove R3 completely (open circuit) and see what VOUT looks like

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the two halves of your breadboard's bus bars aren't connected together. Those red and blue lines are broken in the middle, indicating that they are two individual half-length bus bars.

It's up to you to join each half with a small jumper, if you want them to be continuous from end to end.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t say if this will fix the problem, but the datasheet is pretty adamant about not leaving any floating inputs.

[image: datasheet excerpt]

I suggest you make sure to follow all of the requirements in the datasheet.

Comment: I tested it with all unused inputs connected to GND and the result was unfortunately the same.